# After updating Eclipse, I get an error when creating a new Android project

Tags: android, eclipse, upgrade

I recently updated Eclipse, and now when I go to create a new project it will display an error that says "The SDK doesn't have the directory tool/progaurd.cfg".

How can I fix this?

Also, after you continue with the error there is no `r.java` file...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem before. Updating the Android SDK Tool fixed it. Here is how: "Window" -> "Android SDK and ADV Manager" -> "Installed packages" -> "Update all...".

Answer (score 0):

I too had this same issue. I had other projects too...But it didnt have this error..When I created a new one, one day it came with this error. My error went I placed this file into that folder.

Comment: i placed this file inside android-sdk/tools/lib folder

Comment: which file? my sdk/tools/lib- folder doesn't have that file. can you please clarify.

Answer (score 0):

FIXED IT. All you have to do is, reinstall the update ADT in eclipse. You do this by Help,AVD and SDK Manager,Available packages. Install the latest ones AGAIN even if you have already installed it.

This fixed it for me perfectly. So give it a try!